# ReactJS: Warning on controlled input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using some inputs from Material-Ui. I'm loading the values of these inputs from an API. If the values aren't there, then the user has to type them.

I'm using `Hooks` and the initial state is: `const [bankDetails, setBankDetails] = useState({});`

My inputs are configured like this:

```
                <TextField
                  id="outlined-bank-name"
                  label={t("Bank name")}
                  placeholder={t("Type bank name")}
                  margin="normal"
                  variant="outlined"
                  name="BankName"
                  type="text"
                  value={bankDetails.bankName}
                  onChange={e =>
                    setBankDetails({
                      ...bankDetails,
                      bankName: e.target.value
                    })
                  }
                />
```

This works fine, however everytime I type something a warning shows:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to
>   be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to
>   controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

I don't know the reason, because I defined `value` and `onChange` props.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this warning because you used:

```
const [bankDetails, setBankDetails] = useState({});
```

bankDetails as blank object so during first rendering bankDetails.bankName will be undefined, and input field will get value as:

```
value={undefined}
```

modify your hooks like this:

```
const [bankDetails, setBankDetails] = useState({bankName: ''});
```

Comment: I tried to initialize it with `const [bankDetails, setBankDetails] = useState({ bankName: "", bankCity: "", bic: "" });` but it didn't work

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. When I was receiving the response from the API and filling the object with info, I wasn't copying the last state (initial state), so it was replacing it with no `bankName`.